# Java for loops and 2D arrays

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This code should be so simple, yet isn't working at all. It doesn't do anything. To my understanding it should print out a 10 by 10 grid of random numbers below 21.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Map {
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int coords[][] = new int[10][10];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("dastardly");
        Map.generate();
        Map.show();
    }

    public static void show() {
        for(int i = 0; i >= 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j >= 10; j++){
                System.out.print(coords[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void generate() { 
        for(int i = 0; i >= 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j >= 10; j++){
                coords[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(21);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is composed of three parts:

- Initialization
- Condition to enter the loop and continue looping
- Post action, done after each iteration.

So this loop (and the others too):

```
for(int i = 0; i >= 10; i++){
```

is not working and should be changed to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

If you have some troubles remembering it, think a for-loop as just a while loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  // instructions
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Think a for-loop as just a while loop. The condition is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The terminating condition for the loops is wrong:

```
j >= 10
```

should be

```
j < 10
```

Comment: AIOOBE - use <10 instead; also, missed same problem with `i`

Answer (score 1):

Change

`i >= 10;` to `i < 10;`

and

`j >= 10;`  to `j < 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Working Code :

Changes :

**i >= 10** to **i < 10**

**j >= 10** to **j < 10**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Map 
{
     static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int coords[][] = new int[10][10];
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("dastardly");
        Map .generate();
        Map .show();
    }
    public static void show() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                System.out.print(coords[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void generate() { 
        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                coords[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(21);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
971756192091315
181318132191661920
100141331158018
66131218111611183
12112141501721516
27361013751614
```